# CsvParser misses some places with specified delimeter

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, csvhelper

I have a C# code that suppose to parse data and uses "@BELL" as Delimeter. (BELL is ASCII code)

But some values have another "@" at the end of it, and thus it looks like this "0.0000000@SS-AA&-BB-C)@@021328@STRING_Price".
The CsvParser does split on the first "@" but misses the 2nd occurrence (where it has "@@") and splits fine on the 3rd occurrence.
The data cannot be modified in the source and has to be as it is.

We're using CsvHelper v 15.0.0.

Is it a known CsvParser issue? (I was trying to get away without adding additional parsing/replacement).

Here is my code (I have simplified it and use local file for the test purpose, but in reality it goes to the AzureBlobStorage):

```
private static readonly string delimiter = "@" + new string('\u0007', 1);
private static string filePath = "C:\\Downloads\\000_From_Blob";

private static IEnumerable<string[]> ParseCompressedClientFormattedStream(string filePath, string delimiter)
{
    using (var remoteStream = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        using (var csvReader = new CsvParser(remoteStream, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { Delimiter = delimiter.ToString(), BadDataFound = null }))
        {
                for (; ; )
                {
                    var line = csvReader.Read();
                    if (line != null) yield return line;
                    else break;
                }
         }
    }
}
```

Here are 2 sample lines from the source file. The first line being parsed correctly. But the 2nd one does not split where it has double "@":

```
110@A778@10211@2@Joe@0.0000000@SS-AA&-BB-C)@@SS-AA&-BB-C)@021328@STRING_Price@$9.99@@False
111@A778@10211@2@Joe@0.0000000@SS-AA&-BB-C)@@@SS-AA&-BB-C)@@021328@STRING_Price@$9.99@@False
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have data sample attached to question?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov how do I attach a file to this question? I cannot find an option for it.

Comment: By the way, you can declare your delimiter as `const string delimiter = "@\u0007";` or `const string Bell = "\u0007"; const string delimiter = "@" + Bell;`.  You save a miniscule amount of garbage that way (everything is const, no string constructor called, no runtime string concatenation)

Comment: i tried to reproduce your file in the gist and used your code, it gave me 14-cell arrays, with "@"s in the end of some chunks of the second line. please check it out. everything looks ok for me https://gist.github.com/pwrigshi/00a86d1546d7bd02751c4b2e18378332#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: if you need to have 16 chunks in second case, guess you have to `.Replace("@@", "@BEL@")` first

Comment: @YegorAndrosov, thanks. I guess there is no other choice but to do a replacement before parsing (I was trying to avoid). Weird that it works for you fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in CsvHelper package of v15.0.0.
Updating it to the latest version 15.0.5 - has fixed the issue.